# Hide option in jQuery-UI selectmenu

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectmenu

It is an easy task to hide the option in a select.

```js
jQuery("#bbb").hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="mySelect">
    <option id="aaa">A</option>
    <option id="bbb">B</option>
    <option id="ccc">C</option>
</select>
```

But how does it work in Selectmenu UI ? I can only remove options, but hiding them seems to be impossible.

For example I try to hide the option 'RAL Sonderfarbe' on the select *Farbe*:

Attempt (in dev console):

```
var $el = jQuery('option:contains("RAL Sonderfarbe")');
$el.hide();
$hausfux_laenge_dropdown.find('select').selectmenu('refresh');
```

But it does not work.

[image]

I found a workaround, but if `selectmenu('refresh');` is called, then the option appears again...

```js
$('#mySelect').selectmenu();
var mySelectOpened = false;

$('#mySelect').selectmenu({
    open: function(event, ui) {
        if (mySelectOpened == false) {
            mySelectOpened = true;
            var $el1 = $('#mySelect option:contains("B")');
            var $el2 = $('li:contains("B")');
            
            $el1.hide();
            $el2.hide();
        } 
    }
});

$("#refresh").click(function() {
    $('#mySelect').selectmenu('refresh');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<select id="mySelect">
    <option id="aaa">A</option>
    <option id="bbb">B</option>
    <option id="ccc">C</option>
</select>

<button id="refresh">Refresh Selectmenu UI</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by extending the core jQuery UI javascript and css.

**Example:**

```js
var $el = jQuery('option:contains("B")');
$('#mySelect').selectmenu();

jQuery('#hide_option_b').click(function() {
  $el.attr('hidden',true);
  $('#mySelect').selectmenu('refresh');
});
jQuery('#show_option_b').click(function() {
  $el.attr('hidden',false);
  $('#mySelect').selectmenu('refresh');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/Eddcapone/custom_jquery-ui-1.12.1@master/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/Eddcapone/custom_jquery-ui-1.12.1@master/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<select id="mySelect">
    <option id="aaa">A</option>
    <option id="bbb">B</option>
    <option id="ccc">C</option>
</select>

<button id="hide_option_b">Hide option B</button>
<button id="show_option_b">Show option B</button>
```

I added this to `jquery-ui.css` (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Eddcapone/custom_jquery-ui-1.12.1/master/jquery-ui.css)

```
/* Hidden */
.ui-state-hidden { display: none; }
```

And I changed/added some lines in `jquery-ui.min.js` (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Eddcapone/custom_jquery-ui-1.12.1/master/jquery-ui.js):

**Changed `_renderItem` from:**

```
_renderItem: function( ul, item ) {
    var li = $( "<li>" ),
        wrapper = $( "<div>", {
            title: item.element.attr( "title" )
        } );

    if ( item.disabled ) {
        this._addClass( li, null, "ui-state-disabled" );
    }

    this._setText( wrapper, item.label );

    return li.append( wrapper ).appendTo( ul );
},
```

**to**

```
_renderItem: function( ul, item ) {
    var li = $( "<li>" ),
        wrapper = $( "<div>", {
            title: item.element.attr( "title" )
        } );

    if ( item.disabled ) {
        this._addClass( li, null, "ui-state-disabled" );
    }
    if ( item.hidden ) {
        this._addClass( li, null, "ui-state-hidden" );
    }

    this._setText( wrapper, item.label );

    return li.append( wrapper ).appendTo( ul );
},
```

And `_parseOption` from:

```
_parseOption: function( option, index ) {
    var optgroup = option.parent( "optgroup" );

    return {
        element: option,
        index: index,
        value: option.val(),
        label: option.text(),
        optgroup: optgroup.attr( "label" ) || "",
        disabled: optgroup.prop( "disabled" ) || option.prop( "disabled" ),
    };
},
```

to

```
_parseOption: function( option, index ) {
    var optgroup = option.parent( "optgroup" );

    return {
        element: option,
        index: index,
        value: option.val(),
        label: option.text(),
        optgroup: optgroup.attr( "label" ) || "",
        disabled: optgroup.prop( "disabled" ) || option.prop( "disabled" ),
        hidden: optgroup.prop( "hidden" ) || optgroup.css( "display" ) == "none" || optgroup.css( "visibility" ) == "hidden"
                || option.prop( "hidden" ) || option.css( "display" ) == "none" || option.css( "visibility" ) == "hidden"
    };
},
```

Now hidden options are automatically detected and hidden.

Answer (score 2):

Set the `disabled` attribute to `true` on the option, which will give the generated `li` for that option a class of `ui-state-disabled`, which you can then hide using your CSS:

```js
$(function() {
  var $el = jQuery('option:contains("B")');
  $el.attr('disabled',true);
  $('#mySelect').selectmenu();
});
```

```css
li.ui-state-disabled {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<select id="mySelect">
    <option id="aaa">A</option>
    <option id="bbb">B</option>
    <option id="ccc">C</option>
</select>
```

But then all disabled options are invisible.

Comment: Thx, but then I can't disable options without hiding them.

Comment: The only other option would be delete options from the source select statement, then refresh your selectmenu widget.  That's what I ended up doing.